# No package certbot available

Tags: rhel, lets-encrypt, certbot, epel

I'm trying to install certbot on RHEL server.

[Instructions to enable epel-release](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)

```
# yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

then

`# subscription-manager repos --enable "rhel-*-optional-rpms" --enable "rhel-*-extras-rpms`"

epel-release-7-11 was installed.

```
# yum install certbot
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package certbot available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I even downloaded rpm manually from 
[fedora project epel](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/)

removed and cleared all cache. But install package is not available.

Comment: What does `yum repolist` say? Can you install other packages from epel?

Comment: epel/x86_64  Extra Packages for Enterprise is present. yum install banner part of epel does install.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For future reference, I could install executing the following lines:

```
sudo yum -y install yum-utils

sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional

sudo yum install certbot
```

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-other

Answer (score 5):

It's success for me.

before install certbot, I execute the following lines:

```
 yum remove epel-release
 yum clean all
```

then execute the following lines:

```
sudo yum -y install yum-utils

sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional

sudo yum install certbot
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was wondering why yum install was so esoteric for this widely used product.

Answer (score 4):

For me with same error just using this command simply solved the problem:

```
yum install epel-release
```

seems other sugesstions are a little excessive or unrelated.

Comment: This works because certbot is not part of the default for RHEL or all derivative projects (CentOS, Rocky Linux, AlmaLinux, etc.) but it *is* included in the EPEL repository. EPEL, part of Fedora Linux, is arguably the most official (and ths generally most stable / tested) of the supplemental repositories for RHEL-derived distros, and the ability to install it with yum (or dnf) is included in RHEL. For this reason, I would preferentially install something from it, rather than any other repository.

Answer (score 2):

Go to /etc/yum.repo.d/epel.repo and delete # before the "baseurl" and save it.
after that:

```
yum install certbot
```

on this way my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

In EC2 Amazon Linux do

```
$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

then do

```
$ sudo yum install certbot
```

Comment: Same problem after this on amazon linux 2. No package certbot available.